# Can't ping ip adresses through L2TP VPN

Tags: networking, 20.04, vpn, ping, l2tp

I have a L2TP VPN server(Ubuntu) and Ubuntu 20.04 server. I **connected** to VPN in my Ubuntu, however I can't ping any ip addresses located on that network. What causes such behaviour of that VPN connection? I can provide any necessary information about server configs and etc. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What VPN are you using?

Comment: If you can't reach IPs on the other side of the VPN, that's because of firewall rules or improper configuration on the VPN server side (did you set up proper NAT masquerading?  Did you enable IP forwarding?).  Unfortunately, though, there's not enough information here as is to really assist in debugging this.